# How to access a website on VPS with port create?

Tags: networking, port, domain-name

I try to host my website for learning, on a CentOS free VPS (no support).

I’m allowed to access Apache service via IPv4 by adding a custom port.

Using the format below, I can access the server with my browser.

e.g. 12345 is my custom port that I created for default port 80: 
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:12345

But I cannot access my hosted website http://mywebsite.com (‘the webpage is not available’).

I’ve created the proper DNS record on my DNS provider, and pointed the domain name to the free VPS server IPv6 address (through CloudFlare).

Note: My ISP doesn't provide IPv6 connection and the IP is not ICMP pingable (I can’t create IPv6 tunnel).

Here is my telnet test communication result (not my real IPv6 address):

```
[root@myserver ~]# telnet mywebsite.com 80
Trying 1a12:1234:1:1::1:1a23...
Connected to mywebsite.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
[root@myserver ~]#
```

Why I can’t access my website: http://mywebsite.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay.., what fixed it was adding on Cloudflare a 'CNAME' record in addition to the existing 'AAAA' record.

Hope this help someone.